# Starter Set Cleric's Hit Points don't add up

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-points, pregenerated-characters

In the Starter Set, the [Hill Dwarf Cleric's character sheet](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Charactersv2.pdf#page=3) shows a Hit Point maximum of 11. Shouldn't it be 10 from a 1d8 Hit Die and the Constitution bonus of +2?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The cleric is a Hill Dwarf. Page 13 of [*D&D Basic Rules*](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/basicrules) v0.1 describes the **Dwarven Toughness** racial trait that Hill Dwarves have, which grants +1 hp each level, including 1st.